# Does this regex fail, or do I need to modify the regex to support "optional followed by"?

Tags: python, regex, regex-greedy

I am trying the following regex: https://regex101.com/r/5dlRZV/1/, I am aware, that I am trying with `\author` and not `\maketitle`

In python, I try the following:

```
import re

text = str(r'
\author{
\small 
}

\maketitle
')

regex = [re.compile(r'[\\]author*|[{]((?:[^{}]*|[{][^{}]*[}])*)[}]', re.M | re.S), 
re.compile(r'[\\]maketitle*|[{]((?:[^{}]*|[{][^{}]*[}])*)[}]', re.M | re.S)]

for p in regex: 
  for m in p.finditer(text): 
     print(m.group())
```

**Python freezes**, I am suspecting that this has something to do with my pattern, and the SRE fails.

**EDIT:** Is there something wrong with my regex? Can it be improved to actually work? Still I get the same results on my machine.

**EDIT 2:** Can this be fixed somehow so the pattern supports **optional** followed by ?: or ?= look-heads? So that one can capture both?

Comment: It probably hasn't frozen, but is in the middle of an exponential backtracking.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's not possible to parse LaTeX with regex. You can create a simple (the simplicity depends on your task, of course) LL(1) parser to do that, though

Comment: Your example seems to run just fine on my machine.

Comment: @ForceBru, please explain more about this? Thx!

Comment: @OndrejK., please explain, doesn't it lag? Or take lots of time?

Comment: @JohnSmith, you're about to learn about something fantastic! https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser

Comment: About 0m0.009s, so pretty quick really.

Comment: @ForceBru, so far all my other regex patterns have worked fine in parsing, the **LL** sounds like over complicated to have to deal with something that is more tailored so maybe **LL** would not be a good idea.

Comment: @JohnSmith, this depends on what you're trying to do: if you want to quickly extract some simple structure, regexes may work, but it's not possible to parse a language with recursive patterns, like LaTeX, HTML, XML, etc with a regular expressions because such languages aren't... well... _regular_ (yes, that's an actual term).

Comment: @ForceBru, I see. I am fully aware that *regular* is an actual term. Regexes seem to work more effectively because of what I am actually doing.

Comment: Is there something wrong with my regex? Can it be improved to actually work? Still I get the same results on my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the heading, "Parentheses Create Numbered Capturing Groups", on this site: https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html, I managed to find the answer which is:

```
Besides grouping part of a regular expression together, parentheses also create a 
numbered capturing group. It stores the part of the string matched by the part of 
the regular expression inside the parentheses.

The regex Set(Value)? matches Set or SetValue. 
In the first case, the first (and only) capturing group remains empty. 
In the second case, the first capturing group matches Value.
```